# Mysql query showing error in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out page id which has a short-code. Here is the query I am trying to run in mysql `phpmyadmin`

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE "%[registration id="17"]%"
```

but it is showing following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '17"]%"
```

LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `id='17'` instead of `id="17"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in your sql

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND 
post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE "%[registration id="17"]%"
                                                               ^^^^^^
```

Use `'` instead of `"` in the where like part.

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND 
post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE "%[registration id='17']%"
```

If you really want to match the 
`registration id="17"`, try escape the `"`.

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND 
post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE "%[registration id=\"17\"]%"
```

OR

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND 
post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE '%[registration id="17"]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE "%[registration id='17']%";
```

or

```
 SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "page" AND post_status="publish" AND post_content LIKE '%[registration id="17"]%';
```

Comment: How is this any different from the accepted answer?